# How to determine which hierarchy will be tested and untested in DUnit in app console?

Tags: delphi, dunit

How to determine which hierarchy will be tested and untested in DUnit in app console? When i work in GUI mode, i can check and unchek the hierarcy.

Comment: Commenting out the registration for the tests you don't want to run?

Comment: so, we can not doit runtime ?

Comment: You'd think the test runner would accept command line arguments to control this, or does the developer have to do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 2):

The `ITest` interface in DUnit contains a `Enabled` property. You can assign `False` to this property for tests (and test hierarchies) which should not run.

See [How can I disable DUnit tests by name programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279127/how-can-i-disable-dunit-tests-by-name-programmatically)